# Paraphrasing common knowledge/phrases

Tags: plagiarism

First example: "Ronald Reagan was born in Illinois." (found in multiple sources)
Does this mean that I can never use this exact phrase, since it's in multiple sources? Naturally, I wouldn't cite this at all, but suppose I am attributing it to a source. Do I need to rephrase this?

Second example: "Gerald was an electrician." (source) This is how any English speaker would immediately phrase this. If this isn't common knowledge, do I still have to find a way of paraphrasing it or putting it in quotation marks? Further, when later talking about Gerald, would I never be able to say something like "He knew what to do, because Gerald was an electrician," since it uses that same phrase?

I've heard that one way of looking at it is that you have to paraphrase if creativity has gone into the phrase/sentence, but if it's something so basic like 'the chair is red' or 'the dog is short' (or the two above examples), then you really don't need to paraphrase or quote, though you must cite.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: If I copyright the word "the", will everyone who uses it have to reference me?

Answer (score 2):

First, passing text authored by someone else off as your own can be plagiarism even if the information or idea conveyed in the phrase is common knowledge. It depends on the phrasing's level of originality. There is no steadfast rule about the required level of originality. Clearly, very short phrases such as your examples are less likely to be original. But the originality of a good aperçu often lies in efficiently conveing a known idea: "In the long run, we are all dead" (Keynes).

Second, as a rule of thumb, ask yourself whether the same phrasing is likely to have been used in more than two publications without quotations. If yes, it's not original.

Third, you must provide references (e.g. often citations) to any claim that is not commonly held to be true, not to avoid plagiarism, but to back up your argument with facts. If there is any doubt that Ronald Reagan was born in Illinois, you have to provide a reference for this claim. Since the originality of the phrasing is so low, you wouldn't need quotation marks, unless for some reason you want to flag this as an explicit quotation. (E.g. *Smith (2008) immediately answers the question of Reagan's birthplace on the first page of his book: "Reagan was born in Illinois"* ).

Comment: Very helpful answer. Thank you!